# How to find the size of the adjacency list of the graph in c++?

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I am trying to build a dynamic graph in which when a new node is added the size of adjacency list is increased by 1 and every time the size of graph is calculated.

```
Graph.h
 class Graph
 {
    long long no_of_nodes;    // No. of vertices
    list<long long> *adj_list_of_nodes;    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists

    public:
    void sizeOfGraph ();
    void addEdge(long long, long long); // function to add an edge to graph
    bool isReachable(long long, long long );  // returns true if there is a path from s to d
 };



Graph.cpp
void Graph::sizeOfGraph()
{
    adj_list_of_nodes = new list<long long>[1];

   //I want to find out the no_of_nodes in the adjacency list somewhat like this but this is not working
    this->no_of_nodes = adj_list_of_nodes.size();   
}
```

But since adjacency list is a pointer type list I am unable to find a suitable function to do so. Can anyone suggest how to find the no of nodes in the graph or by using the adjacency list

Answer (score 0):

In case of pointers, just call the method with `->` operator.

```
adj_list_of_nodes->size();
```

Notice that merely, allocating space with `new` will not magically fill the `list`. You need to insert data into the list. The `new` initialization part should go in your class's constructor and the `delete` part in destructor. Ideally you should be using a smart pointer class instead of raw pointers in C++.

Thus, 
 1. Initialize the pointer in constructor.
 2. Fill data into the list.
 3. Return the size. (If data is inserted, then the size will be non-zero)

Note: I dont understand the need for list<>* here. You could just use an object instead of a pointer to one i.e. `list<long long> adj_list`.

**Edit** 
Adjacency list is of the form : [ {vertex} : [ list of adjacent vertices.. ] .. ]

Hence create a map : with key as vertex name(`long long` in this case) and value as the adjacency list.

```
class Graph
{
    std::map<long long, std::list<long long>> adj_list ;

public:
    Graph() = default ;
    void insert(long long, const std::list<long long>&);
    std::size_t size() const ;
};

void Graph::insert(long long v, const std::list<long long>& lt) {
    if(adj_list[v].size() == 0u)
        adj_list[v] = lt ;
    else
        adj_list[v].insert(adj_list[v].begin(), lt.begin(), lt.end());
}

std::size_t Graph::size() const {
    return adj_list.size();
}

int main() {
    Graph ob ;
    ob.insert(1, { 2, 3 }); // vertex 2 and 3 are adjacent to vertex 1
    std::cout << ob.size() ;
}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89dcd0b2a04a54bf) is a generic example. (where your vertex can be any type of data i.e. a `long long`, `char`, `std::string`)

Comment: I tried to output it. But the output comes out to be 0
      
      void Graph::sizeOfGraph(long long no_of_nodes)
     {
 
    adj_list_of_nodes = new list<long long>[no_of_nodes];
 cout << adj_list_of_nodes->size();
    }

    int main()
    {
  
        Graph g;
   g.sizeOfGraph(6);
        return 0;
     }

Comment: I need the adjacency list as after insertion of nodes dynamically I need to find path between various nodes at various steps.